# Append <option> and Select Value From DB

Tags: php, jquery

How to append `<option>` in jQuery with a value from database. For example:

```
<?php
    $sql = "query from database";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (!$result) 
    {
        die(mysqli_error($conn));
    } 

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $name = $row['name'];
            $id = $row['id'];
        }
    } 
?>
```

```html
<select name="selector" id="selector">
   <option value="0">Make Selection</option>
</select>
```

I want to append the value from database to the `select` box. I tried with below codes but the result is blank.

```
$('#selector').find('option').append('<option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name;?>');
```

Comment: display your full code please. I hope you are using ajax.

Comment: Remove the `.find('option')`

Comment: Thanks for the help @RoryMcCrossan. How do I display the value for more than 1 result? Do I need to insert on a while loop for the append.

Comment: Yes, see Mannan's answer for how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select name="selector"> 
          <option value="0">Make Selection</option>
     <?php
         $dd_res=mysql_query("Select DISTINCT designation from emp");
         while($r=mysql_fetch_row($dd_res))
         { 
               echo "<option value='$r[0]'> $r[0] </option>";
         }
     ?>
</select>
```

Comment: May I know how to append it with jquery?

Comment: is there a way without the ajax?

Comment: @Amran that's the code I posted above. without ajax

Comment: ic, thanks for the help @MannanBahelim. Will try yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#selector').append('<option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name;?></option>');
```

Comment: thanks for the help but what if I have to show more than 1 result for the value. Can it be done using append as well

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selector').append('<option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $name;?></option>');
```

via ajax call

```
_.forEach(mem, function(obj) {
    content += "<option value="+obj.id+">"+obj.name+"</option>";
});
$('#selector').append(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'DropdownValues.php',
            data: ,               // if you want to pass data u can use this line or else remoce the line
            success:function(response){
               var select = $('#selector');
             select.find('option').remove();
            $.each(response, function(index, value) {
             $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
            }
        });
});
```

this u have to write in jquery function thwn you will get values and append will not work for this method. you have to use appendTo function.

Comment: sorry but how do I apply the function?